# Visual Studio 2012, Release vs. Debug, Incremental Building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, configuration, incremental-build

I am building a C++ project in Visual Studio 2012 via the IDE. I have two configurations Debug and Release with platform set to x64.

When I touch a .cpp file in the project and build under Debug configuration, only that .cpp file gets compiled again into a .obj file i.e. the other .cpp files are not compiled again. This is the behaviour that I would expect.

However, under the Release configuration, if I touch the .cpp file, all .cpp files in the project get compiled again.

I cannot see a flag or setting in the Release configuration that stops the other .cpp files getting compiled when I have only changed one unrelated .cpp file. Does anybody know the setting that I need to change to get this to work?

**EDIT:** Apologies, I noticed after posting that Properties -> General -> Whole Program Optimization was not set to *No Whole Program Optimization* on the Release build and this was causing all the .cpp files to be re-compiled on each build.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such "flag", it has nothing to do with linking.  You need to run the MSBuild diagnostic verbosity to "Detailed" to see why it is convinced that these other .cpp files need to be recompiled as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your feedback. I have edited the question with the reason that MSBuild was convinced that the other .cpp files needed to be recompiled on the Release build.